# Why does my Surface Pro 3 continue to boot to UEFI screen

Tags: microsoft-surface-pro-3

My Surface Pro 3 boots to the black UEFI screen, it does not boot to the normal desktop.  Anyone know how to get passed this?

Comment: [See this page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro2-surfupdate/surface-stuck-at-bios-or-similar/bfbf2f29-5f6d-4021-8de7-0fe948f7adae)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer from Microsoft Forum:

It happened to me. The touch froze on the screen, and I forced reboot it then it always brought that black screen.

> The way I fixed it was to press volume down and power button, then release when surface appears on the screen. Then it came back to life.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro-surfupdate/surface-pro-stuck-in-uefi-after-hard-reset/1ce81cb4-37d5-4c3c-8ac5-9702b53768e1)

Comment: When I do that, it still goes back to the black screen continuously.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reimaging this machine and it corrected the problem.  But if someone is having this problem at home, I don't know how you would solve this other than to have the OS reinstalled and hope it corrects it.